# Use same controller and view for search and non-search in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an angular application. I have one controller and one view. I would like to use the same view with and without a search field. That means if the user needs to see the search view or the regular view with the data already populated, then I would like to do this with the same controller and view. My thought that was that I could maybe pass an additional parameter from the app.js to decide in the controller if the search field needs to be displayed or not. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution set the params property to an object:

In the app.js:

```
        .state('inventorySearchReport', {
                url: "/inventoryReport",
                templateUrl: "templates/reports/inventoryReport.html",
                controller: "inventoryReportCtrl",
                cache: false,
                params: {
                    search: { value: true }
                }
            })
            .state('inventoryReport', {
                url: "/inventoryReport",
                templateUrl: "templates/reports/inventoryReport.html",
                controller: "inventoryReportCtrl",
                cache: false,
                params: {
                    search: { value: false }
                }
            })
```

In your controller inject $state and use as:

```
$scope.enableSearch = $state.params.search
```

Comment: excellent... and it's very helpful, I don't know about params for state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ng-if** [Angular documentation for ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

First initialize a variable say 
**`$scope.test= false;`** in your controller
suppose you want to display the search field when your data is populated through $http then in that you change

```
{
$scope.test = true;
$http({..})
}
```

and in your view

```
<input type="text" name="search" ng-if="test==true"/> // will display the search when data is populated
```

Comment: I need to be able to set the test variable from the app.js. Is that possible?